# Green screen under intensive use?

Tags: macbook-pro, monterey

I had a large number of processes running prior to this. The entire system stopped during normal use, and a minute later, I was greeted with a green screen, that could not be exited. I restarted, and it was gone. Why does this happen, and how do you avoid it?

*MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2020) with macOS Monterey version 12.0.1 (21A559).*

Comment: Details would help. **HOW** did you restart? What was on the green screen? Was it blank? Was there text and do you remember any of it?

Comment: @SteveChambers The screen was completely blank (apart from the green), and I used the power button in the top right to restart.

Comment: Did you get a message like the one shown here after it rebooted? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200553
If you did, you can click "Report" to get more details

Comment: @Cody No. The message said: "Do you want to reopen the applications that were open?"